# How to select all the points accross all the Glyphs inside a Plot with the Lasso or the Box Tool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I have a plot (`figure`) with several Glyphs (drawn by `plot.circle`) I want to select all the layers at the same time. I have applied a CDSFilter to each `circle`. I am using a `legend` as well to hide or show them. What I want to do is to select only the point of the glyphs which are visible.

```py
# [...]

plot = figure(
    width=600,
    height=600,
    x_range=x_range,
    y_range=y_range,
    x_axis_label='X',
    y_axis_label='Y',
    tools='',                    # they are added later
)

for key in flags:
    view = CDSView(source=self.source, filters=[IndexFilter(flags[key])])

    g = plot.circle(
        x='X', y='Y',
        size=5,
        fill_color=colors[key],
        legend='FLAG {}'.format(key),
        line_color=None,
        selection_color='red',
        source=self.source,
        view=view,
    )
    g.nonselection_glyph = None  # avoids to alter the color of the nonselected points

plot.legend.location = "top_left"
plot.legend.click_policy = "hide"

# [...]

lasso_select = LassoSelectTool(
    # renderers=self.glyph_rends,       # default >> all renderers inside the plot, this is not working either
    select_every_mousemove=False,
)
tools = (
    wheel_zoom, pan, box_zoom, box_select, lasso_select,
    crosshair, tap, save, reset, hover
)
plot.add_tools(*tools)
```

[image]

As you can see in the image only the green points are selected, the blue points are not selected. The current selection is drawn with red color. If I hide the green points with the button on the legend then I can select the blue ones. If I use the Tap tool then it is working as expected, and even if I use Lasso Tool selecting only one point.

### Update

I have posted [an issue on the Git Hub Project](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7573)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved issue

Well it seems that this issue was solve already in the master branch. So I am testing it with the version `0.12.14+25.g675aacf72` built from the master and it is working well. The version `0.12.15dev1` was released as well, I am sure this is fixed in that version as well.

### Previous Solution

I found a workaround before this was solve on the master branch. I have created a new circle glyph plotting the whole ColumnDataSource at the top of the rest of the glyphs

```
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource, Circle, CDSView, IndexFilter
from bokeh.models.tools import LassoSelectTool
from bokeh.models.glyphs import MultiLine, Line
from bokeh.palettes import Reds3
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure
import numpy as np

plot_1 = figure(
    width=400,
    height=400,
    tools="pan,box_zoom,box_select,wheel_zoom,tap,save,reset,crosshair",
)

x = list(range(0,200))
y = np.random.random_integers(200, size=(200))

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

selection = list(np.random.random_integers(100, size=(20)))
view = CDSView(
    source=source,
    filters=[IndexFilter(x[100:])]
)

circle = plot_1.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    size=5,
    fill_alpha=1,
    fill_color='orange',
    line_color=None,
    selection_color=Reds3[0],
    source=source,
    view=view,
    legend='FLAG 1',
)
circle.selection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_alpha=1.0, # transparent
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='orange',
)
circle.nonselection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_alpha=1.0,
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='orange',
)

view = CDSView(
    source=source,
    filters=[IndexFilter(
        x[:100]
    )]
)

circle_2 = plot_1.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    size=5,
    fill_alpha=1,
    fill_color='blue',
    line_color=None,
    selection_color=Reds3[0],
    source=source,
    view=view,
    legend='FLAG 2',
)
circle_2.selection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_alpha=1.0, # transparente
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='blue',
)
circle_2.nonselection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_alpha=1.0,
    line_color=None,
    fill_color='blue',
)

plot_1.legend.location = "top_left"
plot_1.legend.click_policy="hide"

circle_all = plot_1.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    size=5,
    fill_alpha=0.0, # transparent
    line_color=None,
    source=source,
)
circle_all.selection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_color=Reds3[0],
    fill_alpha=1.0, # transparent
    line_color=None,
)
circle_all.nonselection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_alpha=0.0, # transparent
    line_color=None,
    line_alpha=0.0,
)

lasso = LassoSelectTool(
    renderers=[circle_all],
    select_every_mousemove=False,
)
plot_1.add_tools(lasso)

def update_selection(attr, old, new):
    print('>> NEW: {}'.format(new['1d']['indices']))

source.on_change(  # source should be shared along all the plots
    'selected',
    update_selection
)

curdoc().add_root(column([plot_1]))
```

Anyway this was only a temp workaround.